# How to fix my wind barbs so that they plot correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, weather, cartopy

I have been trying to plot wind barbs on a map for my research using Python. After looking through some online guides, I have come up with this result, where the wind barbs plot in the center of the map when they should be plotting at their coordinate location (see image link).

[Wind barb issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVQVd.png)

I am using data from a WRF model run. Here is my code below:

```
# Get WRF variables
wspd_10m = getvar(ds, 'wspd_wdir10', units='ms-1')[0,:]
u10 = getvar(ds, 'U10')
v10 = getvar(ds, 'V10')
wrf_lats, wrf_lons = latlon_coords(wspd_10m)
wrf_lons = to_np(wrf_lons)
wrf_lats = to_np(wrf_lats)
barb_lons, barb_lats = latlon_coords(u10)
barb_lons = to_np(barb_lons)
barb_lats = to_np(barb_lats)

# Timestamp
timestamp = to_np(wspd_10m.Time).astype('M8[s]').astype('O').isoformat()
time = wspd_10m.Time
time_str = str(time.values)

cart_proj = get_cartopy(wspd_10m)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=cart_proj)
plt.contour(wrf_lons, wrf_lats, wspd_10m, colors='black', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.contourf(wrf_lons, wrf_lats, wspd_10m, cmap=get_cmap('rainbow'), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.barbs(barb_lons[::50,::50], barb_lats[::50,::50], to_np(u10[::50,::50]), to_np(v10[::50,::50]), length=6)

plot_background(ax)

plt.colorbar(ax=ax, shrink=0.98)

ax.set_extent([-104.35, -94.45, 36.37, 44.78])
ax.set_title('10m Wind Speed and Direction (m/s) ' + time_str[:19])

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `get_cartopy()`? In `plt.barbs`, you may need to provide some options similar to `transform=??` in doing contour plots.

Comment: Did you check this example: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/barbs.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You are only plotting every 50th point, you are thinning your data too much!  Therefore you only get a single barb in the middle of your domain.

The error is in this this command

```
plt.barbs(barb_lons[::50,::50], barb_lats[::50,::50], to_np(u10[::50,::50]), to_np(v10[::50,::50]), length=6)
```

Change it to every 5th point, experiment with `i` in the following (and I shortened the vector)

```
i=5
plt.barbs(barb_lons[::i,::i], barb_lats[::i,::i], to_np(u10[::i,::i]), to_np(v10[::i,::i]),length=3)
```